# Python pandas create a column and add to DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am collecting data from several tables using pandas.
I have a list of values from which I would like to add to each row in the table in a loop in the form of a column. And I can't figure out how to do it.

Now the code for combining tables into one looks like this

```
result_table = []
for url in urls_list:
    
    response = s2.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    soup2 = BS(response.text, 'lxml')

    
    try:
        table = pd.read_html(url) 
    
    except:
        print('table not exist')
        continue
    
    result_table.append(table)


final_table = pd.DataFrame() 

for t in result_table:

    final_table = final_table.append(t)

final_table.to_excel("razmeri.xlsx")
```

The final_table looks like this:

```
|  1   | RowTable1   |
|  2   | RowTable1   |
|  3   | RowTable2   |
|  4   | RowTable2   |
|  5   | .........   |
```

I would like to add list

```
list = ['259, 178, 305, .....']
```

and to each row of the table from result_table = value from the list

the final_table should look like this:

```
| 259   | RowTable1    |
| 259   | RowTable1    |
| 178   | RowTable2    |
| 178   | RowTable2    |
| 305   | RowTable3    |
| 305   | RowTable3    |
```

I can't figure out how to do it in any way
I will be very grateful if someone helps

Version
pandas: 1.3.1
python: 3.8.0

Comment: can you provide `print(result_table[0].head())`, `print(result_table[1].head())`

Comment: How would you know if the rowtable1 is repeated multiple times?? If we can decode that and get some id, we can map it back to the list and create a column

Comment: @teddcp The number of rows in the table1 or table2 can be different, but pandas shows how many rows are in the table:  
[5 rows x 9 columns]]

it's a good idea - I'll try to take rows in "table"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```py
   Col1       Col2
0     1  RowTable1
1     2  RowTable1
2     3  RowTable2
3     4  RowTable2
4     5  RowTable3
```

Then you can do:

```py
lst = [259, 178, 305]
it = iter(lst)

df["Col1"] = df.groupby("Col2")["Col1"].transform(lambda x: [next(it, None)] * len(x))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Col1       Col2
0   259  RowTable1
1   259  RowTable1
2   178  RowTable2
3   178  RowTable2
4   305  RowTable3
```

Comment: Andrey, thank you very much! It works. You've been very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the issue you are facing with the row numbers on the left are actually indexes generated by Pandas. Combining that with he next part of your question, you want to add the list as a column. This is how you can do it:

```python
import pandas as pd

# Just some static values, instead of these you can use your original values
row_table=["RowTable1","RowTable2","RowTable3","RowTable4"]
list_of_nums = [259, 178, 305, 120]

# Creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Num Value': list_of_nums, 'Row Table': row_table})

# index=False ensures you don't get the row indexes 0,1,2,3... along in your csv
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you mean. But I do not know how to access the table rows in pd.read_html